# turing machine accepting language {ww} has ω($n^2$)

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity, computation-models

prove or disprove that any turing machine which accepts language $l=\{ww | w ∈ \{0, 1\}∗ \}$ has time complexity $ω(n^2)$

Comment: what is $n2$ here? is it supposed to be $n^2$?

Comment: yes ive already modified

Comment: That is not a question. It looks an assignment, yours, probably. I have no issues with anyone asking for help with a specific problem in completing an answer. Waiting for someone else to spoon-feed you is not going to get you far.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-track Turing Machine can accept this language in linear time: (copy the input on the second tape; move the second head to the middle of the word; keep moving both heads right simultaneously and make sure that both heads have the same symbol).

In a single-tape Turing Machine, the time complexity will be at least $\Omega(n^2)$.  The formal proof for a similar problem is given in [Theory of Computation, Kozen: Theorem 1.1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nVE9c-MNRHcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false).

**Intuition:** The finite state automata of any Turing Machine can only store a finite amount of information. We can find the middle position of the input in linear time. To accept the input of the form $ww$, the Turing machine will move its head from the left to the right until it reaches the middle position and checks whether the symbols after the middle position are same as the those at the beginning.
When the head reaches the middle position, *it can only bring a piece of fixed finite information about the symbols from the left part of the word*. Hence, for a long enough word, we need to traverse back and forth multiple times. In each traversal from the start to the end, only fixed number of symbols will be verified, and hence, it should be easy to see, that the time complexity will be $\Omega(n^2)$

The two definition that will probably help you modify the proof given in Kozen for this problem are:

1. For $n = 4k$ , define $L_n = \{ x\#^{n/4}x \#^{n/4} \; | \; x \in \{0,1\}^{n/4} \}$.
2. Define the crossing sequence of the word $x$ to be: $C(x) = \{c_i(x) \;| \; \frac{n}{4} < i \le \frac{n}{2} \;\; \text{ or }\;\; \frac{3n}{4} < i \le n \}$